# Python Organizing A List of Lists into a Specific Format

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

OK, so I have to make a way to create a formatted box that displays a few parts of information that are contained within a list of lists.

I currently have it manually set up to how it needs to look but I need to make it into an automatic setup as I will need to be able to add and remove characters from the list.

This is the code that I have already:

```
def display_characters(character_list, display_type):
if choice == 'list':
    print("===================================================")
    print("-     Character (heroes and villains) Summary     -")
    print("===================================================")
    print("-                              P  W  L  D  Health -")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[0][0],"              ",character_list[0][3],"",character_list[0][4],"",character_list[0][5],"",character_list[0][6],"    ",character_list[0][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[1][0],"                    ",character_list[1][3],"",character_list[1][4],"",character_list[1][5],"",character_list[1][6],"    ",character_list[1][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[2][0],"                 ",character_list[2][3],"",character_list[2][4],"",character_list[2][5],"",character_list[2][6],"    ",character_list[2][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[3][0],"                  ",character_list[3][3],"",character_list[3][4],"",character_list[3][5],"",character_list[3][6],"   ",character_list[3][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[4][0],"                 ",character_list[4][3],"",character_list[4][4],"",character_list[4][5],"",character_list[4][6],"    ",character_list[4][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[5][0],"                   ",character_list[5][3],"",character_list[5][4],"",character_list[5][5],"",character_list[5][6],"    ",character_list[5][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[6][0],"                 ",character_list[6][3],"",character_list[6][4],"",character_list[6][5],"",character_list[6][6],"    ",character_list[6][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[7][0],"                      ",character_list[7][3],"",character_list[7][4],"",character_list[7][5],"",character_list[7][6],"    ",character_list[7][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[8][0],"                   ",character_list[8][3],"",character_list[8][4],"",character_list[8][5],"",character_list[8][6],"    ",character_list[8][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("===================================================")
elif choice == 'heroes':
    print("===================================================")
    print("-     Character (heroes and villains) Summary     -")
    print("===================================================")
    print("-                              P  W  L  D  Health -")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[0][0],"              ",character_list[0][3],"",character_list[0][4],"",character_list[0][5],"",character_list[0][6],"    ",character_list[0][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[1][0],"                    ",character_list[1][3],"",character_list[1][4],"",character_list[1][5],"",character_list[1][6],"    ",character_list[1][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[3][0],"                  ",character_list[3][3],"",character_list[3][4],"",character_list[3][5],"",character_list[3][6],"   ",character_list[3][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[5][0],"                   ",character_list[5][3],"",character_list[5][4],"",character_list[5][5],"",character_list[5][6],"    ",character_list[5][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[6][0],"                 ",character_list[6][3],"",character_list[6][4],"",character_list[6][5],"",character_list[6][6],"    ",character_list[6][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[7][0],"                      ",character_list[7][3],"",character_list[7][4],"",character_list[7][5],"",character_list[7][6],"    ",character_list[7][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("===================================================")
else:
    choice == 'villains'
    print("===================================================")
    print("-     Character (heroes and villains) Summary     -")
    print("===================================================")
    print("-                              P  W  L  D  Health -")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[2][0],"                 ",character_list[2][3],"",character_list[2][4],"",character_list[2][5],"",character_list[2][6],"    ",character_list[2][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[4][0],"                 ",character_list[4][3],"",character_list[4][4],"",character_list[4][5],"",character_list[4][6],"    ",character_list[4][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("- ",character_list[8][0],"                   ",character_list[8][3],"",character_list[8][4],"",character_list[8][5],"",character_list[8][6],"    ",character_list[8][7],"-")
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("===================================================")
```

Bellow is the output of the full list

```
===================================================
-     Character (heroes and villains) Summary     -
===================================================
-                              P  W  L  D  Health -
---------------------------------------------------
-  Wonder Woman                5  5  0  0      90 -
---------------------------------------------------
-  Batman                      6  2  0  4      80 -
---------------------------------------------------
-  The Joker                   5  1  0  4      80 -
---------------------------------------------------
-  Superman                    7  4  0  3     100 -
---------------------------------------------------
-  Catwoman                   12  0  6  6      50 -
---------------------------------------------------
-  Aquaman                     8  2  2  4      30 -
---------------------------------------------------
-  Iron Man                   10  6  3  1      50 -
---------------------------------------------------
-  Hulk                        7  2  1  4      80 -
---------------------------------------------------
-  Thanos                     10  2  0  8      90 -
---------------------------------------------------
===================================================
```

I also need to be able to sort the list by a few values such as health, battles won, heroes, villains, and list all characters.

The code has to stay as the character_list as there are other functions that are using this list but each function can change the list. for example, I will have a function that can reset the health to 100%, and then that would have to change this list so when I sort it the highest health characters are on top, etc.
The characters in the character list must be able to change position and also make it so that you can add new characters within the game that will then be in the list with the same formating.

I'm new to python and don't know how the formatting works. I have tried looking up solutions on google and in here but nothing comes back in a way that I understand how it works.

Also, when I call the display_characters function. the character list is the list of characters and the display type is the filter so 0 is all, 1 is heroes only and 2 is villains only. each character has a 'h' or 'v' depending on if they are heroes or villains

Comment: I would suggest using something like [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to store your data. You can store your data as a dataframe (basically a table) and then you can easily sort and print certain rows/cols that you need.

Comment: Ok, so I should have clarified that I can't use any other programs or extensions. I need to use just the base version of python to do this.

Comment: I have previously used 'texttable' to display table data, so I recommend that you try! [texttable](https://pypi.org/project/texttable/)

Comment: Again unfortunately I can't instal more extensions. Has to be default functions within python

Comment: Then start with using list of dictionaries at least, those are both built-in data types. List of lists is almost always horrible. For the rest, look into how `format` function works. Or make each character proper class, that is most correct approach.

Comment: Do you at least store whether each character is a hero or villain in `character_list`?

Comment: in the character_list they are set up to be as follows:

hero/villain name,

hero/villain true name,

hero or villain: h or v,

Total Fights,

Fights won,

Fights Lost,

Fights drawn,

Current HP.

Comment: @tvm It has to be in a list of lists. Or can I build a dictionary that can then save back to the original list of lists?